# «Завели уголовное дело на...» Корректно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, предлоги, деловой-язык

Юристы настаивают, что есть только один верный вариант: *завели уголовное дело **в отношении** кого-либо.*
При этом в СМИ часто встречается: *завели уголовное дело **на** кого-либо, завели уголовное дело **против** кого-либо.*

Корректно ли употреблять такие формулировки в медиа, учитывая, что стиль уже не официально-деловой?

Comment: Замените "дело" на "расследование" и предлог "на" станет неуместным. Так что какая-то логика в этом есть. Насчет СМИ и корректности можно посмотреть сюда https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYP5gvKhvHc

Comment: но ведь дело и расследование - это не одно и то де. дело - совокупность документов, а расследование - совокупность процессов.

Comment: Тогда все ок: "Завели новый паспорт на машину"/"Завели уголовное дело на Васю".

Comment: если дело и расследование не одно и то же, потому что дело это совокупность документов, то почему уголовное дело можно прекратить? И так пишется в законах.

Comment: @CITBL Ответ есть в БТС, это не только документы.

Comment: @oleedd о чем и речь

Comment: @user190920 если 2 слова являются синонимами, то это еще не значит что после них должны использоваться одни и те же предлоги, а перед ними должны использоваться одни и те же глаголы

Comment: Ну по смысловым оттенкам два слова всегда различаются. Если сильно различаются, то предлоги другие, если слабо, то одни и те же. Как-то так.

Comment: Грамота ру не рекомендует.

Answer (score 0):

Юридические нормы (язык документации) и нормы языка могут не совпадать. Не допустимые в документации вещи могут быть вполне допустимыми в языке.

С точки зрения русского языка последний вариант точно правильный.
Классический вариант: *возбудили против к.-л. уголовное дело*.

Предлог "на" звучит резко, разговорно. Не особо это корректно. Оно может означать следующее: *завели на него папку с документами*. То есть нейтрально, а не делать что-то против кого-то.

"В отношении" — как-то так не очень часто говорят, "против" звучит лучше.

Не стоит распространять это на остальные глаголы (здесь речь о "завели"). С другими глаголами может быть другая история.

В русском языке нормы стилистики нигде не зафиксированы. Правильность определяется частотностью употребления и лексической сочетаемостью.

Comment: в таком случае оба глагола — «возбудить» и «завести» — корректны? какой из них всё же предпочтительнее?

Comment: "Возбудить" предпочтительнее. А заводят — папку/досье **на** кого-то.

Comment: "Завести дело на" широко используется и в СМИ и не звучит разговорно и тем более резко разговорно

Comment: @CITBL В юридических документах так не напишут, поэтому в некоторой степени разговорно. Резко, а не резко разговорно, там запятая стоит, резко по сравнению с "возбудили против".

Comment: человек спрашивал можно ли употреблять такую фразу "в медиа", то есть в СМИ. В СМИ это фраза не звучит ни резко ни разговорно. Вполне корректно звучит и очень частотно

Comment: Да и кстати, вы говорите " завели на него папку с документами" звучит корректно. Так в полицейской официальной терминологии одно и значений слова "дело" как раз и есть "совокупность документов". И эту совокупность обычно держат в папке, которую так и называют и надписывают "Дело №". Точнее их производят уже с такой надписью.

Comment: @CITBL Такая характеристика общая. Оно не может быть разговорным для одного (применения) и не разговорным для другого. Дело в этом. Ваш аргумент немного нелепый. Из вопроса: *При этом в СМИ часто встречается.* Из ответа: *в СМИ используется очень широко*. В других случаях это в тему, но вы не сказали нового этим, автору вопроса чего-то другого хотелось. А третий абзац вы не поняли, там как раз имеется в виду, что дело — это папка с документами. СМИ стараются быть ближе к людям, поэтому иногда используют не совсем литературные выражения.

Comment: Почему оно не совсем литературное? Из чего это следует? Это выражение используется в СМИ не иногда, а довольно часто. По поводу папки с документами: в полиции просто так папку с документами под названием "Дело №" не заводят. Ее заводят при возбуждении уголовного дела, поэтому фраза "завели уголовное дело на" и стала синонимом "возбудили уг. дело против". В юридическом языке, согласен, пишут "возбудили уг. дело", но не в юридическом у фразы "завел уг. дело на" нет оттенка разговорности. Поэтому ответ на вопрос автора "Корректно ли употреблять такие формулировки в медиа" будет "да, коррректно".

Comment: @CITBL Потому что, будь оно литературным, оно подошло бы для документов, литературное ни у кого не вызывает сомнений, а также звучит нейтрально, а здесь резкость, она заключается в самом предлоге: *пожаловался на него, донёс на него, наехал на него, завёл на него* — это как бы действие сверху, чтобы кому-то навредить. Это по сравнению с "возбудили против". Лучше без этой резкости в плане стилистики, то есть нейтральное отношение.

Comment: то есть "на" - это чтобы кому-то навредить потому что "сверху". А "против" - это не чтобы навредить, оно нейтральное. Всего лишь "против кого-то". Понятно. Какой злобный предлог "на". Например в "надеюсь на тебя", "полагаюсь на тебя", "не нарадуюсь на тебя"

Comment: @CITBL Нет, сверху из-за "поставить на", "повесить на него дело". Оно так звучит именно в этой фразе, немного резко, точно не нейтрально. Для литературных выражений характерна нейтральность.

Comment: :)))) "повесить на него дело" звучит конечно резко, но не из-за "на" а из-за "повесить", (но не потому что повесить может у кого-то может ассоциироваться с повешением) .  Насчет "не нарадуюсь" можно и так и так, например "После Каменки нельзя достаточно нарадоваться на здешнюю тишину, на чистый воздух и простоту нравов. П. И. Чайковский"

Comment: @CITBL Из-за глагола в том числе. Вы просто не ощущаете эту коннотацию, потому что она тонкая.

Comment: согласен, я не ощущаю в предлоге "на" никакой "резкой" коннотации, потому что в нем ее нет. В предлогах вообще нет коннотации. Вы просто с потолка ее взяли. Объяснения "потому что действие сверху", звучат несколько смешно, если честно.

Comment: *Материал на него; материал про него.* Улавливаете резкость в первом? *Дело на него; дело против него.* Первое не звучит нейтрально, будто человек неугоден и этим довольны.

Comment: И коннотация не в предлоге, а из-за предлога.

Comment: @CITBL Забыл @ использовать. Оповещение было о сообщениях?

Answer (score 0):

Быстрый [поиск](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%22) в гугле говорит, что "завели уголовное дело на" в СМИ используется очень широко. И в довольно известных: РИА, Газета.Ру и прочих. Лично я не чувствую чего-либо неправильного в такой конструкции.